# How can I set up a Count occurrence?

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up a count occurrence which will count how much people are in an array and then I want to use that number in a calculation to calculate the total money made from the tickets but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do this.

Each `customer_ID` starts with a `c` which I wanted to use as a the search term.

```
def read_info():
    customer_id_list = []
    ticket_id_list = []
    number_of_tickets_list = []
    buy_method_list = []
    ticket_price = 0
    total_for_customer_list = []

    file = open ("Data.txt","r")
    for line in file:

        #Splits the data from the text file into it's corresponding variables.
        customer_id,ticket_id,number_of_tickets,buy_method = line.split(",",4)

        #Adds customer_id into the customer_id_list array
        customer_id_list.append(customer_id)

        # Adds ticket_id into the ticket_id_list array
        ticket_id_list.append(ticket_id)

        # Adds number_of_tickets into the number_of_tickets_list array
        number_of_tickets_list.append(number_of_tickets)

        #Adds the buy_method into the buy_method_list array
        buy_method_list.append(buy_method)

        #Using IF statements the program works out the price for each day which will be later used to calculate the total price for the customer and the total raised for charity.
        if ticket_id in ['F1','F2','F3']:
            ticket_price = 10
        if ticket_id in ['W1','W2','W3','T1','T2','T3']:
            ticket_price = 5

        #converts the ticket_price from a string variable to a integer variable which allows this variable to be used in a calculation.
        ticket_price = int(ticket_price)
        #converts the number_of_tickets from a string variable to a integer variable which will be used in a calculation.
        number_of_tickets = int(number_of_tickets)

        #calculates the total price that will be paid for each customer by multyplying the ticket_Price which was worked out using the 'IF' statements by the number_of_tickets the customer has bought
        total_for_customer = ticket_price * number_of_tickets


    return customer_id_list,ticket_id_list,number_of_tickets_list,buy_method_list,ticket_price,total_for_customer

def find_number_of_people (customer_id_list):




#main program
customer_id_list,ticket_id_list,number_of_tickets_list,buy_method_list,ticket_price,total_for_customer = read_info()
find_number_of_people (customer_id_list)
```

Comment: do you have any code to share? show what you've tried?

Comment: I had tried a couple of things but nothing worked, So far and I gotta say I have no clue where to start again after my fails.

Comment: I was looking for like an example of an count occurrence which reads information from an array that i could use as an reference and get a rough idea from where to start.

Comment: A new answer has been provided, but it could be improved once you provide further information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment under your question, let me guess what you want.

If you want to get the length (i.e. the number of elements in an array), try:

```
len(array_name)
```

So I see you have calculated the total money for every customer, just add them up and you will get the grand total money of all tickets. To do this, try:

```
grand_total = 0
for money in total_for_customer_list:
     grand_total = grand_total + money
```

If I got you wrong, just discuss with me under my answer so that I can reply.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a refactored version of your code. Could you please explain in your question what you are trying to do? Maybe you could finish the `main` function shown below and pretend several functions exists that do what you want.

```
import csv


TICKET_PRICES = dict(F1=10, F2=10, F3=10, T1=5, T2=5, T3=5, W1=5, W2=5, W3=5)
DATA_COLUMNS = ('customer', 'ticket_type', 'ticket_count', 'ticket_total',
                'method')


def main():
    """Process ticket sale information from a database file."""
    data = read_data('data.txt')
    columns = pivot(data, DATA_COLUMNS)
    find_number_of_people(columns['customer'])


def read_data(path):
    """Get all ticket data from a file and start processing the information."""
    data = []
    with open(path, newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for customer, ticket_type, count, method in reader:
            ticket_price = TICKET_PRICES[ticket_type]
            ticket_count = int(count)
            ticket_total = ticket_price * ticket_count
            row = customer, ticket_type, ticket_count, ticket_total, method
            data.append(row)
    return data


def pivot(data, column_names):
    """Convert the data table into a collection of related columns."""
    columns = {name: [] for name in column_names}
    for row in data:
        for key, value in zip(column_names, row):
            columns[key].append(value)
    return columns


def find_number_of_people(customers):
    """What am I supposed to do here? The current goal is not clear."""
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```